# type coercion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I guess I kind of know the differences between == and === in JavaScript, it is that == will do type coercion when compare but === will not. I understand the following code will be true:

```
console.log(true == "1");
```

but when the code below is false?

```
console.log(true == "true");
```

Comment: Just another reason to not touch `==` with a 90-foot pole!

Comment: @ScottKaye I use it all the time with no problems, but I avoid comparing objects of different types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you loosely compare a boolean with a value of another type, the boolean is coerced into a number.

And when you compare a number and a string, the string is coerced into a number.

The full rules are explained in [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

The process is like this:

```
true == "true" ─┐
                ├─ Number(true)   // 1
 1   == "true" ─┤
                ├─ Number("true") // NaN
 1   ==  NaN   ─┤
                ├─ // Comparing with `NaN` always produces `false`
   false       ─┘
```

Comment: > *the number is coerced into a number* ?

Comment: `true` becomes `1`, not `0`.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typos. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

The boolean operand is converted into a numeric value and strings are converted into a numeric value since one operand is a number.

We end up with 1 == NaN. If either of the operands is NaN, the equal operator always returns false.